# why can I login MacBook with different usernames of the same user

Tags: macos, login

I have only one user on my MacBookPro.
When I check the Users & Groups panel, I can see the username of this only user is "xxxyyy", then I also check the home directory of this only user in Terminal and it shows "/Users/xxx".
As a result, I can login my MacBook with the name "xxxyyy" or the name "xxx" as well.
It puzzles me a lot, Could anybody please give an explanation to this ~

Comment: in your Case xxx is the actual Username of the one User it has created in the System and xxxyyy is just the Displayname (think of it as an Alias to the real User) On Mac and i think on most Desktop Linux too you are able to login using both the realusername and also the Displayname

Comment: I think this explanation makes sense, since I just found when I login with xxx(real username) I can run sudo command line while when I login with xxxyyy(display name) I can not, the terminal would ask who am I in latter situation.

Answer (score 1):

When I entered my user name, it has, as standard, the long name and a short name based on the long name - that you can edit to be different if you want.

You can check in the system preferences : users and groups...